# Generating functions for async waterfall with Map

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am trying to produce async function by iterating through the array of  'titles' and passing array of function later to async waterfall.

according to docs:

```
  var asyncFunction = [
    function(callback){
        asyncFunc(1, function(){
            callback(null);
        });
    },

    // page 2
    function(data, callback){
        asyncFunc(2, function(){
            callback(null, data);
        });
    }
  ]
```

The first function takes `callback` as the first parameter, while the second and all subsequent functions function is taking `data` as the first parameter and `callback` as the second.

My question how do I create function conditionally based on the index of map iteration?

Below is !non-working code example to give you an idea what I'm trying to accomplish.

Thanks

```
const asyncFuncs = ['a','b','c'].map( (letter, index) => {

  const args = i == 0 ? [callback] : [data, callback]
  return  function(args...){
        asyncFunc(2, function(){
            callback(null, data);
        });
    }
})

async.waterfall(asyncFuncs, (error, result) => {})
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense to me. How are you going to use `asyncFunction`? Why does the first function call `getData` (and ignore its `callback` parameter), but the second function calls `callback` (and ignores `data`)?

Comment: sorry for typo, just updated the first code snippet. It simply shows how regular async waterfall implementation would worked, with dummy function.

Comment: What do you mean by "async waterfall"?

Comment: see the edit please

Comment: What is `async.waterfall` (except a syntax error)?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I was wrong.
I guess that you want to dynamic waterfall functions base on your data.

```
var yourData = ['a','b','c'];
async.map(yourData, yourAssignFunction, function (err, result) {
    if(!err) {
       console.log('Success: ' + result);
    } else {
       console.log('Error: ' + err);
    }});

function yourAssignFunction(item, callback) {
    if (item === 'a') { // your conditions check here
        // use waterfall 1
        callback(waterfallFunction1);
    } else {
        // use waterfall 2
        callback(waterfallFunction2);
    }
}

function waterfallFunction1(item, callback) {
    async.waterfall([
        function(cb){
            console.log(' -> task1: ', item);
            cb(null, item);
        },
        function(response,cb){
            console.log(' -> task2: ', item);
            cb(null, item);
        }], callback)
}
```